# Removing leading zeros from varchar sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I remove the leading zeros from a number which is in the form of varchar. 
I have tried the following:

Option 1:

```
insert into example_table (columnName) 
    (SELECT
        SUBSTR(columnName2, InStr('%[^0 ]%', columnName2 + ' '), 10)
        from columnName2);
```

With this, the error I get is

```
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-02063: preceding line from xxxx
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

Option 2:

```
insert into example_table (columnName) 
    (SELECT
        SUBSTR(columnName2, InStr('%[^0 ]%', columnName2 + ' '),  
        LEN(columnName2))
     from columnName2);
```

This time I get

```
Error at Command Line:23 Column:87
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "LEN": invalid identifier
```

Option 3:

```
SUBSTRING
    (columnName2, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', columnName2 + ' '), 10));
```

Similar to above, I get

```
Error at Command Line:23 Column:41
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PATINDEX": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

**EDIT**

I think that the trim route might be my best option, however... I am uncertain how to use it in the case I have.

```
INSERT INTO temp_table
(columnNeedTrim, column2, column3, column4, column5) 
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT(
      SELECT TRIM(leading '0' from columnNeedTrim) FROM table),
            table.column2, 
            table2.column3,
                table.column4
                table.column5
        FROM
        table 
        INNER JOIN 
        table2 ON
            table1.columnNeedTrim=table2.columnNeedTrim) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temp_table);
```

I now get an error because my trim function returns multiple row result.

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

I am not sure how to work a trim (or a cast) into the statement above. Any help on that?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this for SQL Server 2008 also?  You had it tagged as such but that was just removed by someone else.

Comment: it is for SQL developer... did not mean to tag for server 2008

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Oracle has built-in `TRIM` functions for strings. Assuming you have a string like `'00012345'` and you want to keep it as a string, not convert it to an actual `NUMBER`, you can use the [`LTRIM` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions096.htm) with the optional second `set`parameter specifying that you're triming zeros:

```
select ltrim('000012345', '0') from dual;

LTRIM
-----
12345
```

If you might also have leading spaces you can trim both in one go:

```
select ltrim(' 00012345', '0 ') from dual;

LTRIM
-----
12345
```

You could also convert to a number and back, but that seems like a lot of work unless you have other formatting that you want to strip out:

```
select to_char(to_number('000012345')) from dual;
```

---

Incidentally, the immediate reason you get the ORA-01722 from your first attempt is that you're using the numeric `+` operator instead of Oracle's string concentenation operator `||`. It's doing an implicit conversion of your string to a number, which it seems you're trying to avoid, and the implicit conversion of the single space - whatever that is for - is causing the error. (Possibly some of your values are not, in fact, numbers at all - another example of why numbers should be stored in `NUMBER` fields; and if that is the case then converting (or casting) to a number and back would still get the ORA-01722). You'd get the same thing in the second attempt if you were using `LENGTH` instead of `LEN`. Neither would work anyway as `INSTR` doesn't recognise regular expressions. You could use `REGEXP_INSTR` instead, but you'd be better off with @schurik's `REGEXP_REPLACE` version if you wanted to go down that route.

---

I'm not sure I understand your question edit. It looks like your insert can be simplified to:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (columnNeedTrim, column2, column3, column4, column5)
SELECT LTRIM(table1.columnNeedTrim, '0 '),
    table1.column2,
    table1.column3,
    table1.column4,
    table1.column5
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.columnNeedTrim = table1.columnNeedTrim
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM temp_table
    WHERE columnNeedTrim = LTRIM(t42.columnNeedTrim, '0 '));
```

(I don't understand why you're doing a subquery in your version, or why you're getting the trimmed value from *another* subquery.)

You could also use `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO temp_table tt
USING (
    SELECT LTRIM(t42.columnNeedTrim, '0 ') AS columnNeedTrim,
        t42.column2,
        t42.column3,
        t42.column4,
        t42.column5
    FROM t42 
    INNER JOIN t43 ON t43.columnNeedTrim=t42.columnNeedTrim
) sr
ON (sr.columnNeedTrim = tt.columnNeedTrim)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (tt.columnNeedTrim, tt.column2, tt.column3, tt.column4, tt.column5)
VALUES (sr.columnNeedTrim, sr.column2, sr.column3, sr.column4, sr.column5);
```

Comment: I discovered this while doing some more research... however I am coming up with another error... I am going to post results in an edit...

Comment: @user1998581 - I think I might be missing something important, or the question is missing something, but I've added a simpler insert statement...

Comment: I am taking values from two different tables (table1 and table2 and inserting their join (because I need them in one row) only if it does not exist in temp_table alraedy... I have to take the one column (columnNeedTrim) and trim the leading zeros because the values in temp_table have them trimmed... therefore it does not recognize if the number is the same because one has leading zeros and one does not.... does that make any sense?

Comment: OK, but that was missing from your `not exists` clause. I've updated mine to show that. I've also added a `merge` version.

Comment: it seems to be working. Thank you so much. The reason that I was doing sub queries that were not needed, quite simply, is I am semi-new to sql and that is the only way I thought it could work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT '00012345' AS zeroWith, TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM '00012345') AS zeroWithOut
  FROM dual;
```

> Result : zeroWith > 00012345 & zeroWithOut > 12345

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server, if you know the data is actually a number, you can just cast it twice. Casting to an `int` removes the leading zeroes, then back to a string for insertion.  I'm assuming you can do something similar in Oracle.

```
DECLARE @vc varchar(100) = '0000000000000000000001234'

SELECT CAST(CAST(@vc as int) as varchar(100))
```

Returns:

```
1234
```

Comment: how would I apply that to the whole row not just one variable?

Comment: You get the invalid number because your value is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to replace it. It will be handled by Oracle.

```
SELECT  TO_NUMBER(num)
FROM
(
        SELECT '00000123' AS num FROM DUAL
);

-- Result:
-- 123
```

Comment: Unless he has a leading space or something - which I suspect from his other comment on @JNK answer

Comment: @DanAndrews - a leading space wouldn't be a problem, but it isn't clear if there are other values that just don't represent numbers at all, and would therefore generate ORA-01722.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following methods:

Option 1: use the ltrim function as Alex said:

```
select ltrim('0005400', '0')
  from dual;
```

Option 2: use the trim function:

```
select trim(leading '0' from '0005400')
  from dual;
```

Oracle trim function has the leading, trailing and both options.

Option 3: use regular expressions:

```
select regexp_substr('0005400', '[^0].+')
  from dual;
```