# Removing leading zeroes in a select* SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to strip the leading zeroes in certain columns of my select statement. I know how to do this if the column names are listed:

For example, in 
SELECT
a,b,c.... if I want to trim column b, I simply do

```
SELECT a, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM b) new name, c....
```

Now I also want to do the same for a SELECT* statement..
Suppose I have SELECT *, and I want to trim the leading zeroes for column b  only. Is there an alternative to go as to convert the SELECT * to a normal select by listing out all columns? It becomes tedious this way.

Comment: If it's a number column, there shouldn't be leading zeros.

Comment: @KrisRice the columns contain data like : "0000000012345", and I want "12345" And column names are in the form of name1.name2

Comment: You will have to parse the cursor using `dbms_sql`. It's too much code for me to write here, but http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml does most of the same steps.

Comment: Yes, it is completely possible with Oracle 18c and PTF **[Is there a way to TRIM all data in a SELECT * FROM statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391862/5070879)**

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered here: [Removing leading zeros from varchar sql developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656790/removing-leading-zeros-from-varchar-sql-developer)

```
select ltrim('000012345', '0') from dual;

LTRIM
-----
12345
```

Comment: I have:  select distinct tablename.*........ where this outputs 20 columns of data, if I want to leave 19 columns the same but for the one column called xyz, trim the leading zeroes for the data in that column, how would my sql statement be transformed?

Comment: just trim the ones you need to > select ltrim(COL_A, '0') trimmed_a, ltrim(COL_B, '0') trimmed_b, COL_C untrimmed_c from mytable;

Comment: I changed my sql to: SELECT DISTINCT tablename.*, ltrim(tablename.xyz, '0'), now I have 21 columns of data, with the original 20 columns plus the column that I wanted to replace one of the old ones with.

Comment: To remove the leading zero, you'll have to enumerate every col with the ltrim. If you also want the raw, then yes there will be 2x the columns returned.

Comment: @KrisRice Actually it is possible to do it without enumerating every column. Oracle 18c offers polymorphic table functions.

Comment: @lad2025 sure but that’s cloud only and not widely used yet so an answer based on that version is not going to work in 99% cases