# How to remove leading 0 from string in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a string looks like this.

```
00000000004000000
00000000001100000
00000001432000000
00000000167700000
```

I want to remove all leading leading 0 from that column, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Same request as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656790/removing-leading-zeros-from-varchar-sql-developer
You can use to_char(to_number(...)) ; e.g. :
select to_char(to_number('00000000004000000')) from dual;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`TRIM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) function:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM col)
```

Answer (score 8):

this will work:

```
select ltrim(colname,'0') from table_name;
```