# Supress leading zeros from oracle table extract to a file

Tags: oracle, datastage

I am extracting data from oracle table to a text file and I have below number columns. When I select the below columns to a file it gives me all leading zeros which I wanted to suppress.

```
Select ltrim(col_1,'0'),ltrim(col_2,'0'),ltrim(col_3,'0') from table1
```

Datatype:

```
Col_1 ---NUMBER(10,2), 
Col_2 ---NUMBER(38,0),
Col_3 ---NUMBER(15,1)
```

Current Output:

```
00000303.44|0| 00000000000008.2    
00000000.00|26| 00000000000030.2    
00000473.40|0| 00000000000010.0
```

Expected Output:

```
303.44|0|8.2    
0|26|30.2    
473.4|0|10
```

Please let me know if i need to change the datatype to get the Expected output. I even tried `TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM col_name)` i did not get the expected output.

Comment: given your example, it appears you want to remove trailing 0's as well; I.E. you just want the numerical value.  Is that the case, or should your sample data say "8.00,363.,0"?

Comment: What is the datatype of those columns?

Comment: I dont think that oracle stores leading zero in number data type column.

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656790/removing-leading-zeros-from-varchar-sql-developer/17657672

Comment: care to comment on the tool used to spool this to a text file ?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the datatypes set in the last output stage of your datastage job. When a column is set a decimal, datastage will fill the remaining positions with leading zeros up to the size if your decimal field.
The easiest way to get around this is to place a transform prior to the file output stage and convert all the columns to a varchar at the last stage trimming all the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is not in number and possibly in varchar/varchar2;

conversion is required;  you can use to_number to address this;

Using one of your sample data in below case

select

to_number(00000000000008.2) as num1,

to_number('00000000000008.2') as chr1,

trim(00000000000008.2)  as num2,

trim('00000000000008.2')  as chr2,

ltrim(00000000000008.2,'0') as num3,

ltrim('00000000000008.2','0') as char3

from dual